# Convert values to a number using excel vba if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I have a column in excel that has two values "Disqualified" and "Open".

I want to use an If Statement using VBA to change the disqualified values to 0 and the Open values to 1.

Here is the excel formula that shows what I want to do

```
=IF(H:H="Disqualified","0","1")
```

I think I need a for loop to loop through all the values in column H but can't seem to get this to work. Thanks

Comment: Just do a find and replace.

Comment: I can just filter and change the values manually, or do a find and replace or a formula. However I'm automating a spreadsheet that I use to import values to the database and I want to write all the processes using vba so no manual work is needed. Thanks

Comment: In that case try turning on the macro recorder, do your manual actions and then modify the resulting code. Come back here if you need help with that last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the code in your [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40832025/6535336), it can (and should) be refactored to get rid of the `Select` parts (which will almost always generate problems in the future).

```
Sub changeValues()
    With Worksheets("your_sheet_name")
        With .Range("H1:H" & .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            .Replace What:="Disqualified", _
                     Replacement:="0", _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     MatchCase:=False, _
                     SearchFormat:=False, _
                     ReplaceFormat:=False
            .Replace What:="Open", _
                     Replacement:="1", _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     MatchCase:=False, _
                     SearchFormat:=False, _
                     ReplaceFormat:=False
        End With
    End With
    'I doubt if the next line is needed
    'ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there is probably a better way of writing this but this macro does the job.

```
Sub changeValues()
'
' changeValues Macro
'

'
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.replace What:="Disqualified", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.replace What:="Open", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
End Sub
```